# Return IDBTransaction in Typescript

Tags: typescript, indexeddb

I'm trying to write some functions that allow a user to build their own transaction with IndexedDB in Typescript.

Calling `db.transction(...)` returns an `IDBPTransaction<...>` which Typescript complains is private.

How can I return an `IDBTransaction` from a function in Typescript?

Comment: this should be a global, check your lib-dom, you might need to add a lib to tsconfig or jsconfig or whatever editor you are using to recognize the additional globals introduced by  indexeddb.

Answer (score 0):

`IDBPTransaction` is actually a type from the `idb` NPM package, not from the native browser implementation.

In order to return an `IDBTransaction` you need to use the IndexedDB API directly.